# Publish progress in doingbackground giving unexpected values in android

Tags: android

When i publish progress in doingbackground its giving me unexpected values in in progress update. after publish, progress bar reach in thousands even in minis sometimes.

> here is my code..

```
 public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;


    public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            //socket
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
            Log.d(Find_People_Activity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            //inputstream
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            //datainputstream
            DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(inputstream);
            //length and .ext(mp4)
            long length=dataInputStream.readLong();
            String extension=dataInputStream.readUTF();
            //filepath to be saved
            Log.d(Find_People_Activity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
            final File f = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("received"),
                    "dropit-" + System.currentTimeMillis() +extension
            );
            File dirs = new File(f.getName());


            if (!dirs.exists())
                dirs.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
            Log.d(Find_People_Activity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
            FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(f);



            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            int total = 0;
            try {

                while ((len = inputstream.read(buf)) != -1) {


                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    out.flush();
                    total += len;
          here is problem >> publishProgress((int)( (total * 100) /length));

                }
                dataInputStream.close();
                out.close();
                inputstream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(Find_People_Activity.TAG, e.toString());

            }


            serverSocket.close();
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Find_People_Activity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "File Copied to :" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            File recvFile = new File(result);
            Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    "com.example.dropit",
                    recvFile);


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "waiting for files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress((values[0]));
        percentage.setText("Loading..." + values[0] + "%");
    }
}
```

> Note

i am getting file length in kbs when i publish progress above file length is about 910000kb from data inputstream.